# Python Expression Trees

Tags: python, tree

I'm having trouble with a question:

Draw the expression tree obtained from the following fully parenthesised algebraic expression:

```
"( ( ( 4 + ( 9 * 3 ) ) - ( ( 6 * ( 2 + 4 ) ) / 3 ) ) + 1 )"
```

Write the elements of the expression tree which are at level 4 (the root node is level 0).  Write the level four elements left to right, separated by a single space.

So far I have the following expression tree:

```
                                  -
                   +                             +
              4           *             /               1
                        9   3        *    3
                                  6    +
                                      2 4
```

and then as far as I know the 4th level elements are:

```
9 3 * 3
```

but it is wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint: the mistake begins at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in root , so it must be `+` with `1` and `-` as its childes. **attend to  your parenthesis !**

```
                              +
                 -                       1
          +           /       
        4   *      *    3          
           9  3  6   +       
                   2   4
```

Comment: OK I edited it thank you. It still seems to not be the right expression tree though.

Comment: So instead of / and 1 the children of + are 1 and -?

Comment: Ok I understand. Because the -1 is seperate. But what would the 4th level elements be then?

Comment: If possible, what would the postorder traversal of this tree be? Any links to help with figuring it out?

Comment: see this links : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wittman/10b.1.10w/Lectures/Lec18.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal and http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/postorder-traversal/